# React hook useState is not mapping array objects correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a form that passes an array of objects to another React Functional Component:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import uuid from 'uuid/v1';

    const NewMovieForm = ( {addMovie }) => {
        const movies = [
            {title: 'Generic Action Movie', director: 'Some Guy', id: uuid()},
            {title: 'Jumpscare Horror Flick', director: 'Some Guy', id: uuid()},
            {title: 'Romantic Comedy Drama', director: 'Some Guy', id: uuid()},
        ]
        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            addMovie(movies);
        }
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="submit" value="add movie" />
            </form>
        )
    }

    export default NewMovieForm
```

Other Functional Component:

```
const SearchAPIResults = () => {
  const [movieList, setMovies] = useState([
    { title: 'Weird Space Movie', director: 'Some Guy', id: 1},
    { title: 'Random Comedy', director: 'Some Guy',id: 2},
    { title: 'Thriller With Nick Cage', director: 'Some Guy',id: 3}
  ])
  const addMovie = (movies) => {
    movies.forEach(movie => {
      console.log(movie)
      setMovies([...movieList, {title: movie.title, director: movie.director, id: movie.id}])
      console.log(movieList)
    })

  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {movieList.map(movie => {
          return (<li key={movie.id}>{movie.title}</li>)
        })}
      </ul>
      <NewMovieForm addMovie={addMovie} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchAPIResults;
```

When I press the `submit` button in the `NewMovieForm` component only the `{title: 'Romantic Comedy Drama', director: 'Some Guy', id: uuid()},` object is added to the list of movies displayed in the browser. The `console.log(movie);` outputs the correct movie object but the `console.log(movieList)` outputs the original 3 objects in the `movieList` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setMovies([...movieList, {title: movie.title, director: movie.director, id: movie.id}])
```

Every time this is called, you're resetting back to whatever's stored in `movieList`, plus one extra movie. So since you do it three times in a row, you end up with the original list, plus the last movie.

If you need to create a new state based on an old state, you should use the callback version of setMovies. That guarantees that you're always working with the most recent version:

```
setMovies(previous => [...previous, {title: movie.title, director: movie.director, id: movie.id}])
```

In your case though, i would get rid of the multiple calls to setMovies and just have one:

```
const addMovie = (movies => {
  setMovies(previous => [...previous, ...movies]);
}
```

Comment: Doh. That's much easier of course. No need to map through each object in the array if it's possible to add the content of movies array to the `movieList` array. I thought that with the map funcion I would add a object to the `movieList` array and then another one, etc etc. Could you perhaps do a small explanation or link on the `previous =>` syntax? Kinda looks like magic.

Comment: You can find more on the function version of set state here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates